# Manually sign an App and add it to an Android project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have an old app I have to support and the keystore for it has been lost. I need to create a new keystore so I can sign my APK and deploy it as an essentially brand new app.

As it is an old App I have an old version of Gradle. I'm currently using `Android Gradle Plugin Version` 2.1.2 and `Gradle Version` 2.10 running on Android Studio 3.5.

If I try and use Build->Generate Signed Bundle or APK from Android Studio I can receive an error saying that my `Gradle Plugin Version` should be updated to 3.2.

Upgrading is causing some issues and also introduces too many changes to my app that I will need to test.

All I need to do is sign the app for delivery. I know that it will be a different app to the previous version and I can solve that issue.

My question is how can I sign my App and add it in such a way Android Studio can do a proper signed release build?

Comment: You might try opening your app in an alternate IDE such as Eclipse.  It's possible Eclipse won't require you to update your Gradle version.

Comment: Thanks very much, I hadn't thought of another IDE and then I figured I could download an earlier version of Android Studio. Turns out 2.3.3 worked perfectly.